# Upgrading 2.0 codeception / test failure

Tags: webdriver, upgrade, codeception

I upgraded codeception to 2.0 and then cept tests no longer work.

```
 C:\Users\Project>php codecept.phar self-update
Codeception version 2.0.0

 Checking for a new version...

You are already using the latest version.
```

Then I run build command

```
 C:\Users\Project>php codecept.phar build
Building Actor classes for suites: acceptance, functional, unit
WebGuy includes modules: WebDriver, WebHelper
WebGuy.php generated successfully. 74 methods added
TestGuy includes modules: Filesystem, TestHelper
TestGuy.php generated successfully. 13 methods added
CodeGuy includes modules: CodeHelper
CodeGuy.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
```

And run the test

```
C:\Users\Project>php codecept.phar run acceptance TestCept.php
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.0.0
Powered by PHPUnit 4.1.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

←[1mAcceptance Tests (1) ←[21m----------------------------------------------------------------     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------
←[37;41m FAIL ←[39;49m

 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------


Time: 9.14 seconds, Memory: 6.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) Failed to test in ←[1mTestCept.php←[21m (C:\Users\Projects\tes
ts\acceptance\TestCept.php)
←[37;41m                                     ←[0m
←[37;41mFAILURES!                            ←[0m
←[37;41mTests: 1, Assertions: 0, Failures: 1.←[0m
```

As you can see the test doesnt work, no reason and there was no problem before the update.

Any suggestion will be welcome. thank you

Comment: I don't know? I just show what I did to upgrade codeception, maybe i did it the wrong way... I didnt touch my test code and it worked before I tried to upgrade

Comment: no need to do that kind of bad-tempered
 answer... click on -1 and have a nice day... I started coding few weeks ago, Nice community!!

Comment: Well if you want to know "how to update codeception correctly", this doesn't make a better question for stackoverflow either (because it is to broad). You need to understand your problem and try to solve it yourself first before coming here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was a bug with php 5.4 which is solved now

https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1069